# TFS build agent and Cloned Virtual Macine: agents deleted on both servers

Tags: tfs, virtual-machine

In preparation for an upgrade from TFS 2012 to TFS 2015, we cloned the existing TFS 2012 build server.  The existing server has 4 build agents (but no controllers) installed.  After cloning the existing server (server 1), the new server (server 2) has four build agents as expected.  The new server was renamed and 'cleaned up' by IT.  However when I delete an agent from server 2, it is automagically deleted from server 1.  This is the case even when the related controller is disabled. Two questions:

Q1: Although we could delete and recreate an agent, we would rather not risk breaking or losing any vital data. How can we delete an agent on server 2 without deleting it from server 1?

Q2: We can live with re-creating the agents if we have to, but what happens if we delete the entire TFS build service from Server 2?  Will we break the existing build service on server 1?  And does this issue indicate we have bigger issues on the new server we need to resolve before we upgrade the build engine to 2015?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 2012 or newer build agents, the build agents are configured to connect to server 1. The build agents though listed on server 2 won't connect to server 2 unless the agent configuration is changed to use server 2.

Comment: Are you speaking of the changing the Agents (server 2) controller, or modifying the agents "Computer Name"?  I do not see in the Agent configuration where I can change the server. On the Agent properties control (on server 2) it lists the computer name as Server 1, however there is no way to change this (textbox is disabled)

Comment: Also will deleting the entire build service on Server 2 break the build service on server 1? (We could delete the service on server 2 while it is off the network to stop any service calls)

Comment: The 2012 and newer build agents contact the server. Agents older than that relied on the server to call them. We had to change that when we introduced VS Team Services because on-prem build machines are usually behind firewalls. Since the newer build agents call the server, you don't need to change them, as they won't call the cloned server.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, after you upgrade the TFS application tier, you would install the new build service. Deleting build agent won't change your build data as the build data doesn't store in the build agent.

Comment: We would like to keep the existing build server (with the 2012 build agent) in place, but create a new server. The new server is a clone of the existing (for build references issues).

Comment: Is there any documentation showing that 'deleting the build agent won't effect your build data'?

Comment: I don't know that we have any docs that explicitly say that deleting a build agent doesn't affect your data, but deleting a build agent or controller will not result in any change to your build data. The build data stored in TFS is not stored in the build agent or controller.